# Memory heap growth while using bookmarks

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-management

My application uses bookmarks to retain access to files in sandboxed environment.
Every time i use 
`NSData *bookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil relativeToURL:nil error:&error];`
or

```
 NSURL *resolvedURL = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:storedBookmark options:nil relativeToURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:FALSE error:&resolveError   ];
```

memory heap grows with non-objects allocations which are not deallocated later.
[image]

I am using ARC. @autorelease blocks makes no difference. Instruments showing no memory leaks.

How to get rid from these allocations? Thanks.

Comment: Are these allocations actually causing problems?

Comment: Yes, the process is designed to run permanently in background and after a while real memory occupied by application increases significantly.

Comment: @Rognarroc Did you got any solution for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

please use the pair of:

```
[url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource];

...

[url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
```